# counting null data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, null, count, pivot-table

let say i have one table, which have data like:

```
name       status
bob        single
bob        single
jane       null
tina       null
shane      married
```

i want if status "single or data null" it means single. so if data empty script can read it as single and can count together.
so i can show result like:

```
Single     Married
3            1
```

i have tried with this and it doesnt work:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(status='single',1,0)) AS Single,
       SUM(IF(status='married',1,0)) AS Married
FROM table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN x.status = 'single' OR x.status IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS single,
       SUM(CASE WHEN x.status = 'married' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS married
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
               t.name,
               t.status
          FROM YOUR_TABLE t) x
```

Comment: SUM(CASE WHEN x.status = 'single' OR status IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS single,
can i do like that?

Answer (score 0):

If you know there are only 'single', 'married', and null as options, this will work:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(status!='married',1,0)) AS Single,
       SUM(IF(status='married',1,0)) AS Married
FROM table
```

Otherwise try

```
SELECT SUM(IF(status='single' OR status is null,1,0)) AS Single,
       SUM(IF(status='married',1,0)) AS Married
FROM table
```

Comment: how to prevent i count double data?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. This will not count any row twice because the conditions are complimentary.

Comment: If you tried the query and still have issues, update the question with the new problems and the new query, and we can see what to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(IF(status='single' OR status IS NULL,1,0)) AS Single,
       SUM(IF(status='married',1,0)) AS Married
FROM table
```