# count concatenate column in mysql

Tags: mysql, count, distinct, pivot-table, concatenation

I want do like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809375/counting-null-data-in-mysql), but for another case that not function.
This is my example table:

```
Date         Model        No      Line       Range       Lot        Status
2010-08-01   KD-G435      1       01         1-100       013A       accept
2010-08-01   KD-G435      2       01         1-100       013A       accept
2010-08-01   KW-TC800     1       01         1-200       001A       null
2010-08-01   KW-TC800     2       01         1-200       001A       null
2010-08-01   KW-TC800     3       01         1-200       001A       null
2010-08-01   KD-R411      1       05         1-100       021A       reject
2010-08-01   KD-R411      2       05         1-100       021A       reject


    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inspection_report` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `Model` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
      `Serial_number` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
      `Lot_no` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
      `Line` char(5) NOT NULL,
      `Shift` char(1) NOT NULL,
      `Inspection_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
      `Range_sampling` varchar(19) NOT NULL,
      `Packing` char(2) NOT NULL,
      `Accesories` char(2) NOT NULL,
      `Appearance` char(2) NOT NULL,
      `Tuner` char(2) NOT NULL,
      `General_operation` char(2) NOT NULL,
      `Remark` text NOT NULL,
      `NIK` int(5) NOT NULL,
      `S` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `A` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `B` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `C` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `Status` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      UNIQUE KEY `Model` (`Model`,`Serial_number`,`Lot_no`,`Line`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=84 ;

    --
    -- Dumping data for table `inspection_report`
    --

    INSERT INTO `inspection_report` (`id`, `Model`, `Serial_number`, `Lot_no`, `Line`, `Shift`, `Inspection_datetime`, `Range_sampling`, `Packing`, `Accesories`, `Appearance`, `Tuner`, `General_operation`, `Remark`, `NIK`, `S`, `A`, `B`, `C`, `Status`) VALUES
(79, 'KD-G435UND', '135X0002', '012A', 'FA 01', 'A', '2010-08-01 14:26:35', '135X0001-135X0100', 'OK', 'OK', 'NG', 'OK', 'OK', '2ver-m302', 25158, 0, 1, 1, 0, 'accept'),
(78, 'KD-G435UND', '135X0001', '012A', 'FA 01', 'A', '2010-08-01 14:24:35', '135X0001-135X0100', 'OK', 'OK', 'NG', 'OK', 'OK', '2ver-m302', 25158, 0, 0, 1, 0, 'accept'),
(77, 'KW-TC800UND', '135X0003', '011A', 'FA 01', 'A', '2010-08-01 09:12:01', '135X0001-135X0100', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'TEST', 25158, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''),
(76, 'KW-TC800UND', '135X0002', '011A', 'FA 01', 'A', '2010-08-01 09:10:01', '135X0001-135X0100', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'TEST', 25158, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''),
(75, 'KW-TC800UND', '135X0001', '011A', 'FA 01', 'A', '2010-08-01 09:08:01', '135X0001-135X0100', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'TEST', 25158, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''),
(63, 'KD-R411ED', '135X0001', '022A', 'FA 05', 'A', '2010-08-01 16:24:04', '135V0001-135V0200', 'OK', 'OK', 'NG', 'OK', 'OK', 'ver-r105', 25158, 0, 1, 0, 0, 'reject'),
(65, 'kd-r411ed', '135x0002', '022a', 'FA 05', 'a', '2010-08-01 09:08:01', '135v0001-135v0200', 'ok', 'ok', 'ng', 'ng', 'ok', 'ver-r105', 25158, 0, 1, 1, 0, 'reject'),
(66, 'KD-G435UND', '135X0001', '023A', 'FA 05', 'A', '2010-09-02 14:24:35', '135X0001-135X0100', 'OK', 'OK', 'NG', 'OK', 'OK', '2ver-m302', 25158, 0, 0, 1, 0, 'accept'),
(67, 'KW-TC800UND', '135X0001', '025A', 'FA 07', 'A', '2010-10-01 09:08:01', '135X0001-135X0100', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'TEST', 25158, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''),
(80, 'KD-G435UND', '135X0001', '013A', 'FA 02', 'A', '2010-09-01 14:24:35', '135X0001-135X0200', 'OK', 'OK', 'NG', 'OK', 'OK', '2ver-m302', 25158, 0, 0, 1, 0, 'accept'),
(81, 'KD-G435UND', '135X0002', '013A', 'FA 02', 'A', '2010-09-01 14:28:35', '135X0001-135X0200', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', '2ver-m302', 25158, 0, 0, 0, 0, ''),
(82, 'kd-r411ed', '135x0002', '014a', 'fa 03', 'a', '2010-09-01 09:08:01', '135v0001-135v0200', 'ok', 'ok', 'ng', 'ng', 'ok', 'ver-r105', 25158, 0, 1, 1, 0, 'reject'),
(83, 'KD-R411ED', '135X0001', '015A', 'FA 05', 'A', '2010-09-01 16:24:04', '135X9901-135V0000', 'OK', 'OK', 'NG', 'OK', 'OK', 'ver-r105', 25158, 0, 1, 0, 0, 'reject');
```

### EDIT

I've tried this query:

```
SELECT Date(Inspection_datetime), Model,
   COUNT(DISTINCT(CONCAT(Range_sampling,Model,Line,Lot_no))) AS lot_qty,
   IF(Status !='reject',1,0) AS accept,
   IF(Status ='reject',1,0) AS reject
```

FROM inspection_report
GROUP BY Date(Inspection_datetime), Model

and get result like:

```
Date(Inspection_datetime)   Model         lot_qty   accept  reject
2010-08-01                  KD-G435UND        1     1   0
2010-08-01                  kd-r411ed         1     0   1
2010-08-01                  KW-TC800UND       1     1   0
2010-09-01                  KD-G435UND        1     1   0
2010-09-01                  kd-r411ed         2     0   1
2010-09-02                  KD-G435UND        1     1   0
2010-10-01                  KW-TC800UND       1     1   0
```

I want to make a table like:

```
Date          lot_qty        accept        reject
2010-08-01    3              2             1         //count in same date become one
2010-09-01    3              1             1       //count in same date become one     
2010-09-02    1              1             0
2010-10-01    1              1             0
```

this query almost near the answer, but i can't count the accept and reject result then grouping in same date.try my query.

Comment: What answer do you get?  (Is it 'accept' = 2, 'reject' = 2?  Or is it 'accept' = 5, 'reject' = 2?)  Why do you expect different values for 'accept' and 'reject'?

Comment: i post the result. i must do this bcoz i need some daily lot judgement. it count how many accept or reject which have by lot_qty. or how many accept or reject from lot_qty.

Comment: if i not use "SUM" it will close the answer. but i need to count them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer:

```
SELECT X.InsDate, SUM(X.lot_qty), SUM(X.accept), SUM(X.reject)
FROM 
   (SELECT 
        Date(Inspection_datetime) as InsDate, 
        Model,
        COUNT(DISTINCT(CONCAT(Range_sampling,Model,Line,Lot_no))) AS lot_qty,
        IF(Status !='reject',1,0) AS accept,
        IF(Status ='reject',1,0) AS reject
    FROM inspection_report 
    GROUP BY Date(Inspection_datetime), Model, Line, Range_sampling, Lot_no) X
GROUP BY X.InsDate
```

Comment: i want if same line,model,lot_no,range_sampling the accept just calculated one.then we group in same date.and if data zero length it means "accept"

Comment: @Insane:try may edited query, it almost near the answer but how to count become each date?

Comment: @Insane: i edited my question may be it make you more understand

Comment: owh..we get wrong count at "2010-09-01", it must be get accept=1 and reject=2

Comment: @Insane: i have edit the "INSERT VALUE".the 2nd query not work

Comment: @Insane:yes i get wrong result for my 1st Query but just at the 2010-09-01. After edit the data, i get lot_qty=3 at that day. so we must count how many accept or reject from "3". there are two same data "kd-r411ed" but they have different in line and lot_no.we must separate them so the result of reject must be 2.

Comment: ah never mind..thanks i get the result correctly.please delete your 2nd answer and add Line,Range_sampling and Lot_no in grouping after Model in Line 10 of your query.